# Shaders not loading in Material preview after crash

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

So I have been building a tube station in blender and everything was working as expected, then blender crashed. It doesn't happen often on my PC and when it has crashed I have had no problems after. On this occasion, since the crash, almost all materials will not load in the material preview **Fig 1**. All materials render properly in cycles **Fig 2** and all objects appear in solid mode ""Fig 3**. I've also provided the materials for the material that is still working **Fig 4**, and a material that isn't **Fig 5**. Any help would be greatly appreciated as having to render everytime I want to see the results of a material is becoming a bit tedious. Thank you.

[image: **Fig 1** Image in Material Preview with broken materials]
[image: **Fig 2** Rendered Image with working materials]
[image: **Fig 3** Solid mode, all objects appearing]
[image: **Fig 4** Working material node]
[image: **Fig 5** Borken material node]